# Change Element Visibility Upon Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

Alright, for those of you who have seen the new Google Page, I am attempting to get a similar idea going on my own webpage.  Basically, I want the image in the middle to fade in upon a mouse moving on the screen. Here is the URL:

http://mageia.rh.rit.edu/

This is the Jquery I am using to get most of the affect:  http://hv-designs.co.uk/2009/01/19/jquery-fade-infade-out/

However, as you might be able to tell, the image loads and then fades out.  What I would like to have happen is for the image to not be seen at all until you move your mouse, just like on the Google webpage.  I was thinking of perhaps changing the image's visibility by javascipt and CSS, but I'm not sure how to go about that.  Ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
div.fade_in { display: none; }
```

You can make it fade in on page load:

```
$(function() {
  $("div.fade_in").fadeIn();
});
```

If you want to wait for the mouse to move:

```
function fade_in() {
  $("div.fade_in").fadeIn();
  $("html").unbind("mousemove", fade_in);
}

$("html").mousemove(fade_in);
```

**Edit:** tested in IE8 (compatibility mode), FF3.5 and Chrome 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mageia.rh.rit.edu//resources/main.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fade_in() {
  $("div.fade_in").fadeIn();
  $("html").unbind("mousemove", fade_in);
}

$(function() {
  $("html").mousemove(fade_in);
});  
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div.fade_in { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="centertext">Welcome to Mageia</h1> 
<h3 class="centertext">The Works of Genii</h3> 
<div id = "container" class="fade_in" > 
<img class="image1" src="http://mageia.rh.rit.edu/resources/Escher.gif" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, +1. Didn't recall that Google waited until the mouse moved. And I suppose that `display:none` is far simpler than messing with the different implementations of `opacity`.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I am looking for, but I can't quite get it to work.  If I make the CSS say display:none, then the images doesn't load at all, even after moving the mouse.  If I set it do visibility:hidden, then the same issue happens with the image loading, then disappearing, then when you move the mouse it re-appears.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**For the CSS:**

```
imageID{opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=00)}
```

This ensures that the image isn't shown until the JS is loaded.

**For the Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("imageID").fadeIn("slow"3);
});
```

This changes the opacity from 0 to 1.

Cheers!